# Error with NSBundle.mainBundle when adding sound

Tags: xcode, swift3, nsbundle

I've trying to create a simple sound board for when a button is pressed a sound is made, however when I used this code

```
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(sound, ofType: "mp3")!)
let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
```

I get an error with "Bundle.mainBundle" orginally it told me to change "Bundle" from "NSBundle" because it has be renamed but when I correct that I get another error saying "Cannot call value for non-function type 'Bundle' "

my entire code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {


let soundFilenames = ["60gs", "check", "dada", "danceforme", "eat", "gods", "irelandbaby", "ko'd", "lefthand", "littlewerp", "nocalls", "precision", "sundaymorning", "surprise", "whothefuckisthatguy", "youlldonothing"]

var audioPlayers = [AVAudioPlayer]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    for sound in soundFilenames {

        do {

            let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource:sound, withExtension: "mp3")!
            let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)

            audioPlayer.append(audioPlayer())
        }
        catch {

            audioPlayers.append(AVAudioPlayer())

        }
    }



}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let audioPlayer = audioPlayers[sender.tag]
    audioPlayer.play()

}
```

}

can anyone help me with this please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all in Swift 3 `mainBundle()` became `main` but why not the real short way:

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource:sound, withExtension: "mp3")!
```

And the init method has been renamed to

```
let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
```

and change the next line to:

```
audioPlayers.append(audioPlayer)
```

Comment: I tried you way and it still gives me an error on that codes saying "value of type 'bundle' has no member 'urlForResource'

Comment: By bad, I mixed up Swift 2 and 3. See the updated answer.

Comment: That did work! however I now get the same errors as the comment I made on the answer below :( I will edit my post to show my full code

Comment: shouldn't that close bracket on the last line be a ; ?

Comment: I don't understand